# Don't search PATH when sourcing a file

Tags: bash, shell, source

Is there anyway in `bash`, and hopefully other shells (some portable method), to prevent `.`/`source` from searching the PATH variable?

Comment: Use `.` or `source` with a relative or absolute path?

Comment: `PATH='' source scriptname` or `PATH='' . scriptname`.  But since PWD is not in your path, with an empty path, what precisely do you expect other than `command not found`?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure parameter you are providing is a path.

```
source_nosearch() {
    param="$1"
    if test "$param" = "${param#/}"; then
        param="./$param"
    fi
    source "$param"
}
```